# LyX document compiled in OSX?

Tags: errors, lyx, mac, wysiwyg

[LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) is a wysiwyg LaTeX editor that I find useful to write exercises fast instead of TextMate that I use for long-term projects. So the below shows an exercise that I would like to print as PDF: however I am getting the following errors `Undefined control sequence` that are very vague. I cannot see any `\begin{document}` or other LaTeX commands in LyX in the view which makes debugging harder than in text-based editors. So

**How can I compile a document in LyX?**

[image]

Comment: the fact that `\mathbb` is what's unidentified means that `amsfonts` (or if you need more symbols, `amssymb`, which loads `amsfonts`) isn't loaded.  so try adding that to your job.  (but i don't know how, not being a lyx user.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you for the observation: I realized from that to search for packages and I found a solution, provided below for new LyX users, nice software :)

Comment: What options do you have set in Document > Settings > Math Options?

Comment: @scottkosty thank you for the observation, added the alternative method [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297346/2956).

Comment: @hhh looks good. I would add that there is an advantage of doing it the LyX way because that way LyX knows about the packages that are being used. This way LyX can load them in the best order (sometimes this makes a difference in LaTeX, although in this case I doubt it).

Answer (score 3):

> Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble

and add your preamble such as `\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}`
 so

[image]

and `CMD+R` to get the document compiled like in TextMate -- it works without writing any `\begin{document}`.

> `Document > Settings > Math Options`

More graphical method as pointed out by the comment is to tongle the settings in `Math Options` like the below and in this case you don't need to add the mathematical packages to `LaTeX Preamble`.

[image]